# Message duplicate in ActiveMQ Artemis is still rejected after the message is consumed

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10, and in my use case I want to avoid having duplicated messages in my queue, so I set the property Message.HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID before sending a message to the queue:

```
ClientConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queueName);
ClientMessage message = consumer.receive();
message.putStringProperty(Message.HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID, hashVal);
```

But the problem is that even after this message is consumed if I try to send another message with the same hashVal value, the new message is rejected. Even when there's no other message with the same hashVal value in the queue.

Is there a way to set duplicate detection to reject messages only if there's a non-consumed message with the same HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID in the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is expected. The duplicate detection ID should be unique for each message. If you use the same ID for more than one message then it may be refused if it hasn't been evicted the duplicate ID cache on the broker. IDs are evicted from the cache based on the size of the cache. Once the cache reaches its configured size it will start dropping the oldest IDs when new IDs are added.